# Oversampling a multi-labeled data set

Tags: classification, multi-class, multilabel, oversampling

Given a data set where each individual data point can be assigned to more than 1 class (a multi-class, multi-label data set), are there any guidelines for calculating oversampling weights, i.e., the probability with which you sample a data point based on the frequencies of the labels within the data set?

This is in the context of multi-label classification; I have a very imbalanced data set.

An obvious answer would be to calculate the weight for each label as the inverse frequency (i.e. `1 / total_number_of_label_appearances`), then average up the weights for a given data point; though I'm unsure if there's any better approaches.

Comment: See https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/54450/55122, and replace integer indicator-of-inclusion variables by continuous weight variables, and I think you get a workable solution?

Comment: Sampling existing data is not a valid statistical procedure.   You must honor the observed sample sizes.  Sampling is only relevant before spending the time and money to acquire the data; probability samples can allow targeting of observations that are most valuable to the analysis.  Once you get the sample, don't discard any of the data by over- or under-sampling.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I’m with you on how undersampling discards data, but how do you figure that oversampling discards data?

Comment: Better to say that oversampling distorts the sample which ruins predictions on future non oversampled data.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the weight for each label as the inverse frequency, then average up the weights for a given data point is done like so with pandas in Python:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd


def oversample(df, len_mult=2, random_state=0) -> pd.DataFrame:
    value_counts = Counter(chain(*df[label_col].dropna()))
    weights = 1 / df[label_col].map(
        lambda li: sum(map(value_counts.get, li)) / len(li), na_action='ignore'
    )
    # Fill in average weight for rows w/o labels
    weights.fillna(weights.sum() / weights.count(), inplace=True)
    extra_df = df.sample(
        len(df) * (len_mult-1), replace=True, weights=weights, random_state=random_state
    )
    df = pd.concat([df, extra_df])
    return df


df = pd.DataFrame([['x1', [3,4,5]], ['x2', [0,3]]], columns=['x','y'])
oversample(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a probabilistic classifier, that outputs a probability of class membership for each class, then averaging the weights or choosing the weights to minimise the maximum imbalance both seem reasonable.  However you would likely to end up with a classifier that grossly over-predicts some classes, so I would subsequently post-process the outputs of the trained model on a label-by-label basis to account for the difference in relative class frequencies in training set and under operational conditions (which basically requires multiplying by the ratio of operational and training set prior probabilities and then re-normalising the probabilities to sum to one).  Unlike the re-sampling of the training set, that can be done on a label-by-label basis.